# How to match two table columns in sql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select, codeigniter-4

I have this code

```
$db = \Config\Database::connect();

$query = $db->query("select * from g WHERE g_status = '0' ORDER BY g_date ASC Limit 10;");
foreach ($query->getResult() as $g) {
    $g_amount = $g->g_amount;
 }

$query2 = $db->query("select * from g WHERE p_status = '0' ORDER BY p_date ASC Limit 10;");
foreach ($query2->getResult() as $p) {
    $p_amount = $p->p_amount;
 }

if($p_amount ==  $g_amount){

echo "do something";

}else{

echo "No match";
}
```

Here I am trying to match between table g and table p.... if any column in table g is == any column in table p regardless of the number of column, do something but it always echo "NO match"

I put "Limit 10" in case there is much number of rows in the table, it will only match the first 10th row with the "ordering" command.

Please I need some help.

Comment: If you are trying to match between two tables, why do both queries only reference one table?  Sample data and desired results would clarify what you want to do.

Comment: Your `foreach()` doesnt make sense. `$p_amount` will always be set to the last item in the iteration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, get data as an array

```
$db = \Config\Database::connect();
$query = $db->query("select * from g WHERE g_status = '0' ORDER BY g_date ASC Limit 10;");
$g_results = $query->getResult('array'); 
$g_amounts = array_column($g_results,'g_amount');

$query2 = $db->query("select * from g WHERE p_status = '0' ORDER BY p_date ASC Limit 10;");
$p_results = $query2->getResult('array'); 
$p_amounts = array_column($p_results,'p_amount');

foreach(array_intersect($g_amounts,$p_amounts) as $amount){
   echo "do something";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a `JOIN` and see if it returns something? Not sure if my syntax is correct, I don't do JOINs very often:

`SELECT * FROM g g_table JOIN p p_table ON g_table.g_amount = p_table.p_amount WHERE g_table.status = '0' AND p_table.status = '0'`